# invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 Error installing homebrew

Tags: homebrew

Trying to reinstall homebrew on Yosemite and recieving the following error - I think it's something to do with my paths, which echo's like this:

```
Callams-MBP:Library callam$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:VimCrypt~01!?΂T?-87Φo?VΕa???SMf???F_??;?_B)Z{ٖzq?#.??Ĕ?    u????.?V:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

And the error I receive in console is:

```
remote: Counting objects: 180057, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (49730/49730), done.
remote: Total 180057 (delta 129161), reused 180057 (delta 129161)
Receiving objects: 100% (180057/180057), 35.93 MiB | 766.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (129161/129161), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
HEAD is now at 3dcf8b5 subversion: update 1.8.9 bottle.
-e:192:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
from -e:192:in `<main>'
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: How is the path set? You need to edit the files that change it

Comment: I've edited them already - in .profile it just has macports code

export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

-  in my .bash_profile it links to my .profile with source ~/.profile - in /etc/paths/ it has 

/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin

Comment: So what file has /opt/X11/bin or /usr/local/mysql/bin in it? (and I assume you have rebooted after those edits)